# Regex expression that includes everything up to a character, but ignores escaped versions of that character

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

I have a string that includes multiple substrings in quotation marks.  I need to divide that string into substrings, where each substring is either a quoted string or text between quoted strings, but it needs to also ignore escaped quotation marks.

Examples:

```
'"hello" "there"'
['"hello"', '"there"']

'MACRO "hello there"'
['MACRO', '"hello there"']

'"hello there" MACRO "again, \"Steve\""'
['"hello there"', 'MACRO', '"again, \"Steve\""']

'KERN \"  "Hello    there, \"buddy\""'
['KERN \"', '"Hello    there, \"buddy\""']
```

I see lots of other Stackexchange answers, but they all are concerned only about extracting the quoted string.  I haven't found anything that will divide the entire string.

I tried using Shlex, but Shlex fails with this string:

```
c = r'KERN  "Hello    there, \"buddy\""'
print shlex.split(c, posix=False)
['KERN', '\\"', '"Hello    there, \\"', 'buddy\\""']
```

The "Hello  there" and "buddy" should be part of the same string.

The closest I have is this:

```
>>> m = re.search(r'([^"]*)("?:[^"\\]|\\.*")', c)
>>> print m.groups()
('KERN ', '\\"  "Hello    there, \\"buddy\\""')
```

The problem is the first group.  I need an expression that says, "grab everything up to but not including the first quotation mark, but do include escaped quotation marks".  I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex with an alternation in `findall`, that takes care of escaped characters:

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|\S+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UOhOnj/1)

**Code:**

```
>>> arr = [ r'"hello" "there"', r'MACRO "hello there"', r'"hello there" MACRO "again, \"Steve\""' ]
>>> reg = re.compile(r'"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|\S+')
>>> for s in arr:
...     print (reg.findall(s))
...
['"hello"', '"there"']
['MACRO', '"hello there"']
['"hello there"', 'MACRO', '"again, \\"Steve\\""']
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `"`: Match opening `"`
- `[^"\\]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `"` and `\`
- `(?:`: Start non capture group

  - `\\.`: Match `\` followed by the next escaped character
  - `[^"\\]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `"` and `\`
- `)*`: End non capture group, match 0 or more of this group
- `"`: Match closing `"`
- `|`: OR
- `\S+`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters

Comment: That almost works.  For this string it fails, 'KERN \"  "Hello    there, \"buddy\""'.  However, I think that's okay, because this string is not valid C anyway, so it wouldn't never actually occur.

Comment: Yes this regex assumes double quotes are balanced in input

Comment: If this worked out, please consider accepting / upvoting